# hbase qualifier filter skips other column families

Tags: hbase

I am applying Qualifier filter on scan to get all read items.

```
QualifierFilter readItems = new QualifierFilter(CompareOp.EQUAL, new BinaryComparator(Bytes.toBytes("read-1")));
readItems.isFamilyEssential(Bytes.toBytes("meta"));
```

Result contains read items but it does not contain other column families.

Result only contains meta column family and read-1 qualifier.

How can I get all CFs  and only read items?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Currently, the operation performed is filter { KeyValue }_in to { KeyValue}_out by keeping only the KeyValue's whose qualifier matches the constraint - this is not what you want to do.  You want to filter out the entire row if the qualifier 'read-1' does not exist.  You can do this with the following logic ( this is in Groovy, but, should make sense )

```
def scan = new Scan()
scan.addFamily('COLUMN_FAMILY'.bytes)

def filter = new SingleColumnValueFilter('COLUMN_FAMILY'.bytes, 'read-1'.bytes, CompareFilter.CompareOp.NOT_EQUAL, new NullComparator())
filter.filterIfMissing = true
scan.filter = filter
```

It's a good start to play around with parameters.  I'm not sure what is in your 'read-1' column, but, if it is non-null, this should do what you want ( or get you closer? ).

Good luck!

Comment: Is there something which only checks qualifier and not the actual value in it

Comment: I've looked and tried, but, never came across anything that worked ( and I spent an embarassing amount of time on it) ... do, I don't know - but - I don't think so...

Comment: Checking just qualifier will be efficient since they are kept sorted internally.So I guess I have to implement my own filter to do this.